# using pipe inside ngx-markdown in angular

Tags: angular, markdown

i have a text inside ngx-markdown like this:

```
<div class="process_description">
    <markdown [data]="process.description"></markdown>
</div>
```

how do i apply a slice pipe with markdown?

if there wasn't markdown i would do it like this:

```
<p class="process_description">
    {{ process.description | slice: 0 : 200 }}
    <span *ngIf="process.description.length >= 200">...</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how much correct it is but i solved it this way:

```
<div class="process_description">
    <markdown>
        <span class="process_description">
            {{ process.description | slice: 0 : 250 }}
            <span *ngIf="process.description.length >= 250">...</span>
        </span>
    </markdown>
</div>
```